# Allowing user to edit posts based on the post status

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, post-status

I have Edit Flow and User Role Editor installed on my news site and I basically wanted to do a system where editors pitch ides worth writing about to contributors. So I would want my contributors to be able to only edit posts where post status is set to pitch. 
The idea is: they login, see a couple of pitched posts, pick the one they like, set the status to assigned and themselves as author and from that moment only they and editors can edit the post. Currently I have it setup so all contributors can edit all unpublished posts so I would appreciate your help.